# Carrito de compras no me permite añadir mas de 2 unidades de un producto

Tags: angular, typescript, servicio, angular12

por favor necesito ayuda, estoy haciendo una tienda online de venta de productos lácteos, el backend lo hice con Node.js y Frontend con Angular 12, el problema es el siguiente:

Ahora,tengo una vista Home donde se listan todos los productos,y tambien hay un componente para el navbar en la parte superior,mi problema es que al agregar un producto por medio del boton Add to Cart, solo se me agregan 2 unidades de ese producto y no permite mas, por mas que le doy clic no me agrega mas unidades de un mismo producto al carrito de compras(accedo al carrito dando clic en donde dice Cart dentro del navbar).

[image: Vista del home(página de inicio)]

Ahora, al dar clic en el boton Add to cart, se emite un evento que se comunica con el servicio de Cart para agregar un producto, por cierto debo decir que la cantidad de un producto yo la he denominado como oferta,y por defecto es 1, asi como se ve abajo en el código.

```
onAddToShoppingCart(product: Product) {

    product.oferta=1;
    this.storeService.addProduct(product);
    this.total = this.storeService.getTotal();
  }
```

Entonces, al momento de llamar al servicio verifico si el producto existe, si no existe lo agrega al carrito que lo he llamado myShoppingCart, caso contrario, si el producto existe hago que incremente en 1 la oferta(cantidad).Aparte he creado un Observador para el carrito,éste observa el arreglo myShoppingCart cada vez que se ejecuta el método addProduct dentro del servicio.

CartService.ts

```
private myShoppingCart: Product[] = []; //Carrito de compras

private myCart = new BehaviorSubject<Product[]>([]); 

myCart$ = this.myCart.asObservable();  //Observador del carrito



addProduct(product: Product) {
   
    let indice = this.myShoppingCart.findIndex((p) => p.id === product.id);
    if (indice == -1) {
      this.myShoppingCart.push(product);
    } else {
      this.myShoppingCart[indice].oferta++;
    }
   
    this.myCart.next(this.myShoppingCart);
  }
```

En la página exclusiva del carrito me subscribo al observador para escuchar cada vez que se añada un producto, y guarda ese data que me devuelve en un array de productos para renderizarla en la vista html.

MyCart.component.ts

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.storeService.myCart$.subscribe((data) => {
      this.products=data;
    });
  }
```

**Para terminar, me percaté de algo y es que si bien es cierto solo puedo agregar 2 unidades de cada producto, si luego de hacer eso me voy a la pagina de carrito me muestra la 2 unidades del producto que haya agregado, pero si me regreso de nuevo al home, y aplasto el botón de Add to Cart, si me agrega una 3ra , 4ta y todas las unidades que quiera del producto**.

ENTONCES,tal vez el problema podría estar en el metodo AddProducto del servicio, o el Observador del carrito, pero la verdad que he intentado de todo para solucionarlo,pero hasta ahora no he encontrado una solución.Si podrían ayudarme, se los agradecería infinitamente.

Answer (score 0):

yo también soy relativamente nuevo utilizando Angular pero creo que se que puede pasar aquí. En el método addProduct, la última línea de código debería ser:

```
this.myCart$.next(this.myShoppingCart);
```